# Library for reading an HTTP response in a file-like manner?

Tags: python, http

I need to make an HTTP request with Python to download a large file, but I need to be able to read back chunks of the response using a file-like pointer, somewhat like this pseudo-code:

```
request = HTTPRequest(GET, "http://localhost/bigfile.bin")
request.send()

response = request.get_response()
print "File is {} bytes long.".format(response.content_length)

while True:
    chunk = response.read(1024)
    print "Chunk Length: {}".format(len(chunk))
```

Is there an API like this? I only want to read from the source whenever the `read` method is called, not bringing anything into memory from the response (except the headers) until I want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Check out the [`Requests` package](http://python-requests.org/).

You can use the [`stream` option](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) to avoid fetching the response body until you access it:

```
req = requests.get('http://localhost/bigfile.bin', stream=True)
print "File is {} bytes long.".format(req.headers['Content-Length'])

while True:
    chunk = req.raw.read(1024)
    print "Chunk Length: {}".format(len(chunk))
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'`.

Comment: @TK: Hmm. Works for me here (Windows, Python 2.7 x64, latest version of Requests from PyPI).

Comment: I had a strange problem where `easy_install` only installed version 0.8 for some reason. Fixed now.

Comment: @TK: Great :-) Configuration problems are annoying!

Comment: True. Strange that `pip` installed the right version whereas `easy_install` did not.